# i'm using old code and i want to know how to update mixins in it

Tags: dart, flutter, mixins

i'm using a code of my friend and struggle with the issue that the dart language updated and the mixins syntax is changed...

Main Model class

```
class MainModel extends Model with UserModel, ProductsModel {}
```

this syntax is changed and i don't know how to fix it...
the error is on UserModel and ProductsModel says:

> [dart] The class 'UserModel' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object. [mixin_inherits_from_not_object]

and this is UserModel Code:

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

import '../model/user.dart';

class UserModel extends Model {
  User _authenticatedUser;

  void login(String email, String password) {
    _authenticatedUser =
        User(id: 'assddssa', email: email, password: password);
  }
}
```

anyone can help please...
i'm a beginner in both Flutter and Dart so excuse me for that...

Comment: Maybe show us your `UserModel`

Comment: @RémiRousselet  

i've added the UserModel class code

Comment: That's not helpful when `UserModel` again extends a class which code you didn't post.

Comment: So what exactly i have to do now ?